# postgres database encoding and client encoding different

Tags: python, postgresql, encoding, utf-8

I am currently working with an existing code base. The project needs postgres as back end and it can function normally. Basically the project needs to read from ISO-8859-1 encoded file and post the content to database. The encoding setting for database:

```
cs_db=> show server_encoding;
 server_encoding 
-----------------
 UTF8
(1 row)

cs_db=> show client_encoding;
 client_encoding 
-----------------
 UTF8
(1 row)
```

This is the log printed by the project:

```
2016-12-19 09:17:16 - cs - INFO - SET client_encoding='LATIN1'
```

The project is written in Python 2.7. When reading from the file, it uses the raw way--binary format:

```
with read(filepath, 'rb') as infile:
    for line in infile:
        process_line(line)
```

And I am just confused by this--based on my understanding, this program should break but instead it did not with the following record:

```
cs_db=> select * from cs.tbl where "KEY" = 102023;
 rec_id_ |       rec_tm_       | KEY  |  OFID  | OFCD |                  OFNM                   | del_tm_ | old_id_ | new_id_ 
---------+---------------------+--------+--------+------+-----------------------------------------+---------+---------+---------
  158012 | 2016-04-09 10:41:20 | 102023 | 117354 | CB   | Mr. David Charles Brink M.Sc., D.Com.   |         |         |        
  158013 | 2016-04-09 10:41:20 | 102023 | 534788 | CE   | Mr. Karel Johan Grové AMP               |         |         |        
  158014 | 2016-04-09 10:41:20 | 102023 | 534794 | CF   | Mr. Philip Dieperink BCom (Hons), CTA,  |         |         |        
(3 rows)
```

So the second record selected above contains some non-ascii character. But the database is happy to store and select the record.

so my guess is that postgres did the conversion of encoding for me. but I am not sure. I thought I have to set the client encoding as UTF-8 to make it work?

EDIT:
is this the correct link? [postgres doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/multibyte.html#MULTIBYTE-TRANSLATION-TABLE). thanks

Comment: What client driver are you using? `psycopg2` should default to the database encoding.

Comment: I am using psyciog2, but the client encoding is set explicitly already